# Automated build pipeline Salesforce Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, salesforce, build-automation, continuous-deployment

I am trying an automated build process in Azure DevOps for Salesforce. whenever a change is pushed to the repository, my build is triggered and it is working fine and pushing the changes to the related sandbox. Here is the proof for the same
[Success Build Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QxBe.png).

The configuration of the build is [Build configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ5as.png).
The build is working fine as expected. I now want to create a release which will push this change to a different environment, and I don't want this to be automated, hence the option of creating the release. The build path to the ant file in my release is exactly as it should be but I am getting this error. [Release Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kntYW.png).
The release configuration is [Release configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8V43.png)

My Repository folder structure is: [Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DasPx.png). and my build.xml is within the deploy folder.

I don't know what I am doing wrong but the release is always failing and giving me the error which says: 
Error: Not found antBuildFile: D:\a\r1\a\deploy\build.xml
Not found antBuildFile: D:\a\r1\a\deploy\build.xml

Comment: What does the download artifacts step in your logs say?

Comment: I have attached that error in the Release error screenshot.

Comment: I didn't ask for the error. I asked for the output of the "Download Artifacts" step.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the first image (Success Build Process), seems that you already have deployed your changes on that sandbox. Working with metadata deployment in Salesforce is different from java and .net, keep in mind that you already have the "executables", all those XML are already the code that you will change on the environment.

The second point is that on release you are in another agent, Buil and Release pipelines runs have their own lifecycle, so the code existing at the Build pipeline is not available until you send it on "drop" artifact, see [Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task documentation. So that use copy task to put build.xml on publish folder, then you'll be able to use it on Release pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

When you are executing ant go the **/deploy** folder and execute your command or check for your ant version using ant -version command.

Comment: The ant step is invoked by azure's hosted agent and you have to give the path to the deploy folder where the build file is kept.